# Why does image scale not work in reStructuredText when generating html files?

Tags: html, web, jekyll, restructuredtext

I use reStructuredText to generate my static blog web pages. And I use the command below to include an image:

```
.. image:: /images/01.jpg
   :scale: 50
   :align: center
```

However, the image displayed on my blog web page remain the same size as the original image. Seems that the `scale` option does not work. So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `scale` option to work, the generator needs to know the size of the image. So, you either need to define the size explicitly with `width` and `height` (well, not the solution we're looking for), or you need to install the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to let the converter identify the image size automatically.

Reference: [reStructuredText specification](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image).